# Computing full Electron-Nuclear Interaction Integrals using Obara-Saika Scheme?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

Following my previous question [Here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162846/can-electron-repulsion-integrals-be-negative), I had been trying to implement One and Two electron integrals in the code. I am currently stuck at the implementation of the OS Scheme, where I read the references [1] and [2] to look for the implementation. I understood the recursion parts where the electron is transferred from one center to another using the following recursion relations:
$$ \theta^N_{i+1,j,k,l,m,n}=\theta^N_{i,j+1,k,l,m,n}-X_{AB}\theta^N_{i,j,k,l,m,n}$$
$$ \theta^N_{i,j,k+1,l,m,n}=\theta^N_{i,j,k,l+1,m,n}-Y_{AB}\theta^N_{i,j,k,l,m,n}$$
$$ \theta^N_{i,j,k,l,m+1,n}=\theta^N_{i,j,k,l,m,n+1}-Z_{AB}\theta^N_{i,j,k,l,m,n}$$
$$ \theta^N_{0,0,0,0,0,0} = F_N(pR^2_{PC})$$
where A and B are centers of the the basis functions and ordered set (i,k,m) and (j,l,n) are the angular momentum terms in x,y and z direction, and N is the order of Boys function. My question concerns the calculation of total integral from this scheme.

References:

1. Helgaker, _Modern Electronic Structure Theory
2. Obara. S, and Saikia. A, *Efficient recursive computation of molecular integrals over Cartesian* J. Chem. Phys. 84, 3963 **(1986)**
   Gaussian functions

Comment: Perhaps, you can specify in a bit more detail what your question is.

Comment: @ErikKjellgren, I am trying to understand the implementation of OS Scheme for computing one and two electron integrals. I have understood what the individual terms in the equation are, and how the integrals are computed. My question was regarding the total value of the integral, like do we stop when we reach the max of i, j, k, l, m and n?

Comment: yes we stop when we reach the angular moment we want.